# Conditional Gaussian Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, gaussian

> The random variable $x$ has normal distribution $N(10,1)$. Find $p(x\mid (x-10)^2 < 4)$.

I have been trying it for hours. I tried to solve $\mathbb{E}[(x-10)^2]$ using $\mathbb{E}[ay + b]$ but I'm not sure if it works for $x^2$.

Maybe with the $\mathbb{E}$ and $\mathbb{V}ar$ I can plug into another formula for conditional Gaussians.

Comment: You know that $(X-10)^2<4 \iff 8<X<12$, right?

Comment: If you let $E=\{(X-10)^2<4\}$ then $f(x|E)=\frac{f(x)}{\mathbb{P}(E)}$ for $x\in E$ and $f(x|E)=0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This plot may help you see the appropriate integral:

[image]